# How to find the number of cells which are in exponential format in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-2003

I copied a table from the database and paste in [excel-2003](/questions/tagged/excel-2003).
But some of the cells are automatically converted to **exponential** format. 
I know how to change the format of a single cell. But is there any way to

1. Change the formats of all the exponential cells.
2. How to know the number of cells affected by the automatic exponential format change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Select your column
- Press [ctrl](/questions/tagged/ctrl)[f](/questions/tagged/f) together
- under `Find What` enter ***
- Click `Format` and either select your numeric format directly, or click *Choose Format From Cell* (Step 1 below)
- Press `Find All` to list all the cells (Step 2 below)

**Step1**
[image]

**Step2**
[image]

Answer (score -1):

I got the answer.

I just gone with the same method which I was using for a single cell.

Select `Column ---> Format Cells..`

In `Number` Tab `--->` select `custom --->` Select `0` instead of `general`
and its solved.

Comment: My answer lets you pick out the cells that you need rather than an overall format